# Performing XML Transformations in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, xslt, air

I'd like to be able to run an xml transformation using an xslt file in my AIR project. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AIR 1.5, a version of Webkit with support for XSLT is included.

Use the class `XSLTProcessor` from JavaScript just like you would in Firefox. (Note: There is one annoying bug. Stylesheets cannot contain non-breaking spaces, no matter whether literally or as a character reference.  I am told that more recent versions of Webkit will fix this issue.)

Below is a complete example.

Create a file `test.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XSLT test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <!--
      function test() {

        // Step 1: Parse the stylesheet
        var stylesheet
          = "<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'"
          + "               version='1.0'>"
          + "  <xsl:template match='/'>"
          + "    Hello World from XSLT!"
          + "  </xsl:template>"
          + "</xsl:transform>";
        var stylesheetDocument
          = new DOMParser().parseFromString(stylesheet, "application/xml");

        // Step 2: Parse the source document
        var source = "<dummy/>";
        var sourceDocument
          = new DOMParser().parseFromString(source, "application/xml");

        // Step 3: Perform the XSL transformation
        var xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
        xslt.importStylesheet(stylesheetDocument);
        var newFragment = xslt.transformToFragment(sourceDocument, document);

        // Step 4: Show the result
        document.body.appendChild(newFragment.firstChild);
      }
      // -->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" onclick="test()">
    Output:
  </body>
</html>
```

and a file `test.xml`

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.0">
  <id>test</id>
  <filename>test</filename>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>test.html</content>
    <visible>true</visible>
  </initialWindow>
</application>
```

You can try it using the debugging runtime, for example:

```
adl test.xml
```

Klick the button, and it will say:

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [lichteblau.com](http://www.lichteblau.com/tmp/stackoverflow-xslt.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

XSLT support is typically provided by browsers. The version of Webkit embedded in AIR does not support XSLT. So, you'll have to do this all by yourself. I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/xpath-as3/wiki/GettingStarted) project that lets you play around with XPath queries in AS3. Now, template parsing and node creation you'll have to do by yourself.