# How can I reference a Flash file's own filename from actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In our pipeline, we ultimately publish HTML5 using Toolkit for CreateJS. However one of the steps to get us to that HTML5 includes publishing an SWF that outputs some Javascript code. I've mostly managed to automate this using JSFL. However, at present there is one line of AS3 that our artists have to find on the timeline and change manually, but it interrupts their workflow, and if they miss it or mess it up it is hard to catch, so I would like to automate it too:

```
Object(root).log.text +=  "        root.skillAnime189 = factory();\n";
```

From the above, "skillAnime189.fla" is the name of the .fla file which contains this code. This is the case if the artist is working on Skill Animation #189, but if he is doing #304 or #6 or #1022 (no padding) the number changes accordingly, and he has to update that line accordingly.

So, I would like to change that line to something like:

```
var flaName:String = getThisFlashFileName().split(".")[0];
Object(root).log.text +=  "        root." + flaName + " = factory();\n";
```

but I am at a loss as to how to access the name of the .fla file containing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to get the swf name is to parse `stage.loaderInfo.url` parameter:

```
    var url:String = stage.loaderInfo.url;
    url = url.split("?")[0];    //remove query string after "?"
    var swfname:String = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    trace(swfname);
```

output:

```
astest.swf
```

But this code gives `swf` but, rather than `fla`, so you need to maintain the same names for `flas` and published `swfs` (any case usually they are the same, so it shouldn't be the problem)