# Flex 4: XML Literals with conditions

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, e4x

Is there any way to do something like the following (pseudocode) in Flex:

```
var x:XML = <xml>
  if(condition){
    <tag>hello</tag>
  }
</xml>;
```

which would return `<xml><tag>hello</tag></xml>` if the condition was true and `<xml></xml>` (or `<xml/>`) if the condition was false?

ADDITIONAL NOTE: I know how to append children, etc. I am looking for a way to do this in the literal expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was really amazed at how simple it is, and at how powerful AS3 can be. The following actually worked:

`var x:XML = <xml>{condition ? <tag>hello</tag> : ""}</xml>;`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `appendChild` method:

```
var sample:XML = <sample><items/></sample>;   
if( condition ) sample.items.appendChild(<tag>hello</tag>);
else sample.items.appendChild( </tag> );
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to do this inline in the literal. My actual XML is more complex than that (and the node where I would have to append the child would be deeper inside)

Comment: Hmm.. maybe with an xslt? I guess you'd have to create it externally and then import it.. but AFAIK there isn't any logic available inside an XML tag declaration.

Comment: that's what I feared. I was hoping for something inside braces that would return a string and be "lifted up" as markup

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449367/performing-xml-transformations-in-flex

Comment: Ugh; kind of complex. I think I have found what I need (will post the answer)